# left bar button is not responsive from extreme left side

Tags: ios, swift

I want to shift left bar button to extreme left of the navigation bar. by using this code I can able to shift this. I noticed button is not responsive from 20 px from left side(before arrow in yellow rectangle, its not responsive). From middle of the button it is responsive and go to back screen. how to fix this.  I used following code [image]

```
let suggestButton = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
suggestButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 40)
suggestButton.setImage(backImage, for: UIControl.State.normal)
suggestButton.backgroundColor = .green
suggestButton.imageEdgeInset = UIEdgeInset()top: 10.0, left: 5.0, bottom: 10.0, right : 35)
 suggestButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showPopover(sender:)), for:.touchUpInside)

 suggestButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -15, y: 0)
 let suggestButtonContainer = UIView(frame: suggestButton.frame)
 suggestButtonContainer.addSubview(suggestButton)
 let suggestButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: suggestButtonContainer)
 navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = suggestButtonItem
```

Comment: Those 20 points are the left inset plus the translation transform. They are outside the superview (the bar button item). You cannot tap something that is outside its superview.

Comment: @matt Any solution to move superview to extreme left? please suggest

Comment: No, what you’re trying to do is totally unsupported. That is not how a navigation bar works. If you use the framework you must use the pieces that the framework gives you.

Comment: As a workaround, instead of using the navigation bar, you can add a custom UIView where the nav bar would be and add a title label and button and it should work.

Comment: You can use the debug hierarchy in the future to see the various layers that produce the view. This will just give you visual confirmation of matt's response right now.